# Efficiently list every unique pair of points in a grid

Tags: algorithm, grid, iteration

Seemingly an easy problem, I am looking for an algorithm to list every unique pair of points in a grid that are not collinear with the origin. The trick is to somehow avoid all the different symmetries and coincidences. This is what I have so far:

```
for( int x1 = 0; x1 <= s; x1++ ){
    for( int y1 = 0; y1 <= s; y1++ ){
        if( x1 == 0 && y1 == 0 ) continue; // P1 is coincident with origin
        for( int x2 = x1; x2 <= s; x2++ ){
            for( int y2 = 0; y2 <= s; y2++ ){
                if( x1 == x2 && y2 >= y1 ) continue;
                if( x1 * y2 == x2 * y1 ) continue; // points are collinear with origin
                // this is a valid point
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Not `y2 <= y1` ? By the way, instead of the test on `x2/y2` inside the innermost loop, you could use the initialization `int y2= x1 == x2 ? y1 + 1 : 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enumerate all unique pairs (by defining an order on the grid points) and disregard those that are aligned with the origin.

```
def Pair(X0, Y0, X1, Y1):
    if X0 * Y1 != X1 * Y0:
        # Non collinear with the origin
        Accept(X0, Y0, X1, Y1)

# Enumerate all (X0, Y0)
for X0 in range(NX):
    for Y0 in range(NY):
        # Enumerate all (X1, Y1) > (X0, Y0) in the lexicographical sense

        # 1) X1 == X0, Y1 > Y0
        X1= X0
        for Y1 in range(Y0 + 1, NY):
            Pair(X0, Y0, X1, Y1)

        # 2) X1 > X0
        for X1 in range(X0 + 1, NX):
            for Y1 in range(NY):
                Pair(X0, Y0, X1, Y1)
```

Or, better:

```
# Enumerate all (X0, Y0)
for X0 in range(NX):
    for Y0 in range(NY):
        # Enumerate all (X1, Y1) > (X0, Y0) in the lexicographical sense
        for X1 in range(X0, NX):
            for Y1 in range(0 if X1 > X0 else Y0 + 1, NY):
                if X0 * Y1 != X1 * Y0:
                    # Non collinear with the origin
                    Accept(X0, Y0, X1, Y1)
```

Comment: Yep. Regarding the efficiency of this process: O(N^4) pairs are generated; among these, at most O(N^3) are aligned (imagine a line from the origin to the first point; it crosses at most N other points). Less than a fraction 1/N of the pairs fail the test, and the process is optimal.

Comment: It is O(N). N represents the number of point pairs in the grid. So, for example, if the grid is 20x30, then if the algorithm loops about 600*600/2 times, then it is O(N).